# DataSource containing a null value makes ComboBox fail

Tags: linq, data-binding, combobox, c#-2.0, datasource

I've thrown myself headfirst into C# and .Net 2.0 using Linq, and I'm having a few problems debugging some of the problems, namely the following:

I have a ComboBox control (`cmbObjects`) I want to populate with a set of objects retrieved using Linq. I've written a helper method to populate a `List<T>` generic:

```
class ObjectProvider
{

    public static List<T> Get<T>(bool includeNull) where T : class, new()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        LutkeDataClassesDataContext db = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        IQueryable<T> objects = db.GetTable<T>().AsQueryable();

        if (includeNull) list.Add(null);

        foreach (T o in objects) list.Add(o);

        return list;
    }

    public static List<T> Get<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        return Get<T>(false);
    }
}
```

I verified the results when calling the function with true or false - the `List` does contain the right values, when passing `true`, it contains `null` as the first value, followed by the other objects.

When I assign the `DataSource` to the `ComboBox` however, the control simply refuses to display any items, including the `null` value (not selectable):

```
cmbObjects.DataSource = ObjectProvider.Get<Car>(true);
```

Passing in `false` (or no parameter) does work - it displays all of the objects.

Is there a way for me to specify a "null" value for the first object without resorting to magic number objects (like having a bogus entry in the DB just to designate a N/A value)? Something along the lines of a nullable would be ideal, but I'm kind of lost.

Also, I've tried adding `new T()` instead of `null` to the list, but that only resulted in an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Also, I've tried to declare the `List` as `List<Nullable<T>>`, but the compiler won't allow me to do that.

Comment: what is the intent behind adding a Null Value to a List whose elements that the Combobox is supposed to display as individual items?

Comment: I was meaning to use this control to display a weak binding relation. In the database, the relation is defined as a nullable int, which I'd like to represent as a choice the user can make by selecting a blank value in the ComboBox.

Comment: Would love to see a better answer to this.  I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems the `DataSource` becomes invalid if you try to add a `null` value. The solution was to just add the items via a simple `foreach` loop with an empty string at the start instead of assigning the `List<>`.

Answer (score 1):

The combo box control has an option to append data bound items to the hard-coded items in the list.  So you hard-code your n/a value, and data bind the real values.

Comment: Pretty sure that if you add DataBind a collection you can't manually add items as well - it's an either or operation...

Comment: Not true.  In your aspx file you can specify hard-coded list items, and set the attribute AppendDataBoundItems to true.  Then when you do DataBind() it appends the data rows to the hard-coded items.